# “New Screenshot” button is disabled in Xcode Organizer

Tags: mac, iphone, screenshot, xcode

I have connected my iPhone to my Mac.
When I open Xcode Organizer, the New Screenshot button is disabled. 
Any idea why?

Xcode Version 4.3.2
iOS 6.0.1

[image]

P.S: I posted this in apple.stackexchange but got only 8 views in many hours. So posting here again. Hope thats ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have enabled the developer mode for this particular iPhone. Only then it enables that button. I have checked this and it works for me now after enabling that.